# How can I organize my React.js program to remove orders with a button from a list of orders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, components

I'm new to the world of React. I wrote a React.js/Node.js program that visualize orders taken from a database, then I'd like to add the possibility of delete these orders through buttons. I'm not really clear on how to organize the code to make it work.
Obviously the first time I pass the list to visualize from the App.js component I should use the list "initialOrders" and not "orders" because of the rendering method of React.js but then I don't know how to update the state.

Then server side I'd like to make a query to the database to remove the order.

That is what I tried:

OrderList.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function OrderList({ initialOrders }) {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([initialOrders]);

  const HandleClick = (orderId) => {
    alert("I remove the item "+orderId+" from the db");
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/removeOrder/${orderId}`)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {              
            const updatedOrders = orders.filter((order) => order.order_id !== orderId);
            setOrders(updatedOrders);
          } else {
              console.error("Error deleting an order");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        })
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Orders list</h2>
      <ul>
        {orders.map((order, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <div id={index}>
                <p>ID: {order.order_id}</p>
                <p>Nome: {order.customer_name}</p> 
                <p>Data: {order.order_date}</p>
                <p>Totale: {order.total_amount}</p>
                <p><button id={order.order_id} onClick={() => HandleClick(order.order_id)}>Remove order</button></p>
              </div>
            </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default OrderList;
```

A part of server.js (Node)

```
app.get("/api/orders", (req, res) => {
  
  db.query("SELECT * FROM orders", (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Errore during the query to the db:", err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Error during the query to the db" });
    } else {
      console.log(results);
      res.status(200).json(results);
    }
  });
});

app.delete("/api/removeOrder/:orderId", (req,res) => {
    const orderId = req.params.orderId;
    console.log("Order to delete: " + orderId);

    db.query("DELETE FROM orders WHERE id = ?", [orderId], (error, results)=> {
      if (error) {
        console.error("Errore deleting the order:", error);
      } else {
        const msg = "Order successfully deleted";
        console.log(msg);
        res.status(200).send(msg);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but I can identify a few issues to help you make your code functional:

1. Within your `HandleClick` function, you're making a call to the `useEffect` Hook. It's important to note that Hooks should not be called within loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always utilize Hooks at the top level of your React component. In your specific example, there's no need to call the `useEffect` function at all.
2. The API endpoint you're using, `/api/removeOrder/:orderId`, corresponds to an HTTP DELETE Method. You need to specify this HTTP method in the fetch() function to make it work correctly. Without specifying, fetch() will always assume its a GET Method call.

```
// Updated HandleClick
const HandleClick = orderId => {
  alert('I remove the item ' + orderId + ' from the db');
  fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/removeOrder/${orderId}`, {
    method: 'DELETE'
  })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        const updatedOrders = orders.filter(order => order.order_id !== orderId);
        setOrders(updatedOrders);
      } else {
        console.error('Error deleting an order');
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
};
```

There are additional areas for improvement in your code, but given your status as a beginner, I hope these suggestions are helpful for your learning journey.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My doubt is on how to create of the buttons for each element of the order list, because I don't know whether to use another React component or not. The way I thought about it is to use the list called orders to display the orders passed by the parent component App.js and then work on this list and then update the visualization of orders at runtime: the problem, however, is that the setState operates only after the first rendering and therefore the list is not displayed initially, while using the initialOrders list directly in JSX yes. I hope I was more clear